# Process and child Thread ram usage

Tags: python, linux, multithreading, process, gunicorn

I am using `gunicorn` with two worker to run a Flask API for deploying an ML model. And I open Htop and press F5. It show like below:

[image]

and I expand process with PID `246598`. It show like below:

[image]

1. I wonder that are **child processes** with PID: `247243, 247161,...` is actually **child threads** of **father process** with PID `246598`?
2. And I see that these **child processes** use `0.2% MEM` each, so each of them actually use `0.2% MEM` or only the **father process** use `0.2% MEM` and other child processes don't use that much.

Because I scare that if Gunicorn clone identical processes so many times like that, it would use so many ram.

Thanks you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the `free` command to see the total `used` memory on the machine before and after starting the server.  Looking at things like top can be misleading because a lot of the memory is shared (cloned) between threads or even processes and shared libraries.

If you really want to dive deep, `cat /proc/meminfo` to get super detailed stats on all memory usage in the system like kernel caches, and do a before and after server startup comparison.

And yes linux is annoying because many tools don't distinguish threads vs processes... a thread on linux is just a process with a few tweaks, both are started by clone(2)